Crystal Reports Assistance
Quantiy On Hand+Quantity in Process - Quantity Order = QTY Available
Trying to filter to only show me lines less than 0
I have a report that has a formula that calculates per inventory item the following.
Quantity on Hand + Quantity in Production = x then subtracts quantity on order.  I am looking to filter my report to only show me the shortages so anything that formula returns a value of <0 I want to see.
The selection expert does not allow me to filter based on a formula field in the report.

One option would be to use a formula to suppress  the section where the data prints when the result indicates there is a shortage.
To suppress the records you will want to open the Section Expert and select the section where the data is located.  Then edit the formula for the "Suppress" property to include a formula similar to the following.
{x} >= 0

This formula will evaluate the result of your On Hand Qty plus the Qty to be Produced and suppress the entire section when the formula above evaluates as true.
Bear in mind please that suppressed sections are still considered part of the report.  Suppressing the section just prevents it from printing to the report.  This means that any Summary Fields or Running Total Fields that are in your report may still include data from suppressed sections.  Running Total Fields can usually be fixed by setting their Evaluate property to a formula that allows them to only evaluate data when the formula's result is true.  However, if you already are using the Evaluate property for another reason, this may may not work.

I don't beleive this works for my particular report.. Although I could be doing something wrong.. If I could only post a screenshot it would better help me explain..  Thank you for your response.  Figured out adding screen shot

An alternate option would be to create a database stored procedure in your database.  Then all of the record selection can be handled by the stored procedure.  This requires DBA access to the database, as well as some SQL knowledge.  If you don't have DBA access to the database, a SQL Command in the Crystal Report might be another option, but I have no experience with this approach.
